# How to call directive multiple times on node click in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive

I am using custom directive to refresh my page. I have coded my UI with D3. Its a simple graph comprised of nodes and links.

Here is what I am trying to do.
When I click on particular node of graph it expands into its sub graph and so on.

For this following is the controller

```
*vrmUI.controller('CompleteViewController', function($scope,$location, $rootScope, $route) {
    // Assigning data 
    // onDeviceClick is called when node of graph is clicked. 


    $scope.onDeviceClick = function(item){
        $rootScope.pageContextObject = $route.current.data;
        $scope.clickedItem=item;
        $scope.completeObject =//JSON Data
        $scope.loadExpandedView=true;
        $scope.showExpandedView=true;
    };*

});
```

Corresponding html is

```
<div class="content-panel clearfix">

    <div id="topoheader" style="font:12px sans-serif"></div>
        // expandedView directive should get called when ever control goes inside onDeviceClick.

        <expanded-view ng-show="showExpandedView"
            ng-if="loadExpandedView" clicked-rack="clickedItem"  network-data="completeObject"
            device-click="onDeviceClick(item)"></expanded-views>    
    </div>
</div>
```

device-click is called on click on nodes of the graph.
And directive is
*

```
vrmUI.directive('expandedView',function(){ 
    function link(scope,el,attr){
     // Processing when clicked
    }
    return{
        restrict : 'E',
        link: link,
        scope : {
            clickedItem : '=',
            onDeviceClick : '&deviceClick'
        }
    };
});
```

*

Question:

When I click once it works perfectly but when I click on other nodes of graph I can see control going inside   $scope.onDeviceClick = function(item){ but my directive not getting called as happened in first case. Is there anyway by which I can make this happen? Please let me know if you need more details or question is unclear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the lines below to the beginning of the `$scope.onDeviceClick` function:

```
$scope.loadExpandedView=false;
$scope.showExpandedView=false;
```